# Protractor custom locator fails to locate the element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

I have added a custom data attribute to the elements i need to identify and interact using protractor. The attribute is `data-test-id`. I created a custom locator in the `onPrepare` callback in `conf.js` to detect the element. It is below:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    by.addLocator('testId', function(value, parentElement) {
      parentElement = parentElement || document;
      var nodes = parentElement.querySelectorAll('[data-test-id]');
      return Array.prototype.filter.call(nodes, function(node) {
        return (node.getAttribute('[data-test-id]') === value);
      });
    });
  }
```

My angular app has a `h1` with the text Home inside it. I added the `data-test-id` attribute to it:

```
<h1 data-test-id="test-element">Home</h1>
```

Here is my Protractor test:

**test.js**:

```
describe('Navigate to the website.', function() {
    it('Should have the Heading as Home', function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8888/#/');
        browser.waitForAngular();

        var textValue = 'Home';
        var heading = element(by.testId('test-element'));

        expect(heading.getText()).toEqual(textValue);
    });
});
```

**conf.js**:

```
exports.config = {
  //directConnect: true,
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['test.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },

  onPrepare: function () {
    by.addLocator('testId', function(value, parentElement) {
      parentElement = parentElement || document;
      var nodes = parentElement.querySelectorAll('[data-test-id]');
      return Array.prototype.filter.call(nodes, function(node) {
        return (node.getAttribute('[data-test-id]') === value);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

When I run the sample test, I get the following error:

> 1) Navigate to the website. Should have the Heading as Home
>   Message:
>        NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.testId("test-element")

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this issue and get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are getting the attribute, you should ask for `data-test-id` instead of `[data-test-id]`. Looks like a copy-paste error.

Replace:

```
return (node.getAttribute('[data-test-id]') === value);
```

with:

```
return (node.getAttribute('data-test-id') === value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It was a stupid mistake on my part.. :|

Comment: Hi, I tried the above solution, still, I am getting the 'No such element' error, my code:    **conf.js** `by.addLocator('customLocator', function(attribute, value, parentElement) {
            parentElement = parentElement || document;
            var nodes = parentElement.querySelectorAll(attribute);
            return Array.prototype.filter.call(nodes, function(node) {
                return (node.getAttribute(attribute) === value);
            });
        });` and       **testfile.js** `element(by.customLocator("ng-if","$select.open")).click();`. Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and below solution solved my problem :

```
by.addLocator('lid', function(value, parentElement) {
        var nodes;

        if(parentElement)
            nodes =  parentElement.querySelectorAll();
        else
            nodes = document.querySelectorAll('body *');


        return Array.prototype.filter.call(nodes, function(node) {
            if( node.hasAttribute("lid") && node.getAttribute('lid') === value)
                return node;
        });
    });
```

querySelectorAll() needs to give the input as 'tag', if no parentElement is sent then it queries all the tags under 'body' tag otherwise all elements from the parentElement. After that loop through all the elements and check whether attribute 'lid' exists or not. If exists verify the value, if the value is desired value then it returns that element.